# US Keyboard, remap braces

Tags: keyboard, remapping

I have bought an US laptop with US keyboard but didn't come with a key next to Z that type the braces < >.

I don't have experience with keyboard mapping, i would like help to be able to map the Right Ctrl key, to be the braceleft < and the Shift+Right Ctrl to be the braceright >.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xmodmap.

Create a file named `.Xmodmap` in your home directory, and add the following code:

`keycode 105 = less greater`

Save the file, logout and log back in. If the bindings do not take, run `xmodmap .Xmodmap` from the terminal and add the command to your `.bashrc` file.

More details: 
You can see individual keycodes by running xev in the terminal and pressing any key. xmodmap -pk will print all the current keybindings and names of keys.

Comment: Doesn't  your keyboard have < and > above the comma (,) and period (.) as all US keyboards? Still useful to know how to remap keys. I use code similar to the above to map right control to Menu on my older keyboard that lacks this key.

Comment: Yes it has those keys, but i use Portuguese layout with it, so they type differently.

Comment: Of course. That makes perfect sense. I'm glad it is working.